# Hide checkbox item when it is checked, otherwise keep it visable

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I want to hide a checkbox item when it is checked and after the user clicks a button all selected checkboxes should be hidden. If the checkbox is not selected then keep the items visible. Also I am trying to get another button to make all hidden checkboxes visible again. this is what I have so far.

```
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="Tester">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Test1"> Test1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Test2"> Test2<br>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hide").click(function(){
    if($("div").prop("checked"))
    {
        $("div").hide()
    }
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("div").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('div').prop('checked')` won't do anything, since it's not a checkbox.

Comment: Not to mention this is ALL the divs in your html, not just `#Tester`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wrap the checkbox and its label. I have wrapped in label. Here you go:

```
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="Tester">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Test1"> Test1<br>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Test2"> Test2<br>
    </label>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
      $("#Tester input:checked").each(function(){  $(this).parent('label').hide() })
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#Tester label").show()
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Using *.each()* you can iterate over all elements `$("div").each()` , classes `$(".red" ).each()` or ids `$("#name").each()`, and then verify if it is checked and hide it (since the text isn't attached to the checkbox , I put the text and the checkbox inside a div, and hid the div - using [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to access the parent div)

*keep in mind that this will iterate over ALL inputs elements, but you can verify that too inside the loop

```js
function hide_cb(){
    $( "input" ).each(function() {
      if ($( this ).prop('checked') ){
        $( this ).parent().hide();
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">item 2
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">Item 1
</div>

<button onclick="hide_cb();">hide</button>
```